# using rsync incremental 25gb

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I need same help on taking backup my production server to staging server using rsync and i have around 25gb of data which my production which get added 200mb every day.

1 it has to incremental 
2 we are using centos 4.X
3 with 8gb ram 2tg hdd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For backups, I recommend [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/). It's fairly comprehensive, fast, and does incremental backups very easily.

It's freely available, but I don't know if there are any premade CentOS packages for it.

rsync can also be used, (rdiff-backup already uses librsync) but rsync doesen't store the increments it transfers. With rsync you can easily keep a copy of your data, but you can't easily keep the change history of your data.

Comment: I respect your suggestions thanks but we looking some thing do with rsync

Answer (score 3):

- [Dirvish](http://www.dirvish.org/)
- [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but if can suggest us using rsync

Comment: They both use rsync.

Comment: I'd also add backuppc to the list. Similar to Dirvish, but comes with a nice web UI.

Comment: Thx for BackupPC. Nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The rsync docs have an example that might do what you want: http://rsync.samba.org/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Also, if some is compressed files that change a little (but keep the same names), gzip --rsyncable will keep changes minimized to make rsync need to copy less.